# Cleaning up after exceptions thrown during contruction

Tags: java

I'm currently instansating a number of objects within my constructor that require the .close() be called on them when you're done. If in that sequence one object throws an exception, how do I clean up the objects already allocated so far. This presents an issue where the calling function (even if it used try-finally) would never get a reference to call the .close as the object never finished construction.

Thoughts I've had:

- catch the base Exception class and call close on everything that isn't null (however you are not supposed to catch the Exception class)
- use a finalizer (considered bad practice as a finalizer is [not a 'second chance' to clean up](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/288724)).
- instaniate these objects in a "load" or "start" method (consumers of the class need to know to call this method and also means the object is temporarally in an incomplete state between construction and the call to this method)

Example code:

```
class MyClass implements AutoCloseable {
  private EarthConnection earth;
  private SolarConnection solar;
     public MyClass() {
        earth = new EarthConnection();
        solar = new SolarConnection(); // exception thrown by this connection
     }

     public close() {
        if (earth != null) { 
            earth.close();
        }
        if (solar != null) {
            solar.close();
        }
    }
}

   // Caller
   try (MyClass myClass = new MyClass()) {
       // do work - note if MyClass wasn't fully constructored it can't call the close method on it.
   }
```

In the example above how do I clean up the allocated EarthConnection if the SolarConnection throws an exception?

Comment: Why aren't you supposed to catch exceptions? If you need to clean-up when an error occurs I think you must catch the exception inside the constructor to keep it self-maintained. Another, possibly better, option is to use dependency injection but you still have to catch and act on exceptions although outside of the constructor.

Comment: Provide code please or give us the classes the relation between the them.

Comment: Couldn't `MyClass` implement `AutoCloseable` ?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I don't think that changes anything as the caller doesn't have a reference to the object to call .close it but I've added it.

Comment: @TownCube The caller doesn't, but if you instantiate `MyClass` within a try-with-ressources, it could close all its composants depending on your own implementation of `close()`

Comment: @YassinHajaj You're saying try-with-resources can call the close() method on an object which never finished construction (due to an exception being thrown in it's contructor)?

Comment: @TownCube No it couldn't indeed. I misunderstood the problem I think.

Comment: I'm moving over years, to insert into construtor only 'safe' code, not effecting in external resources, and things like `open()` using in full constructed objects (in methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad practice to rely on catching exception from constructor. I would recommend to use factory method an catch exception there: try...catch with recources

Answer (score 1):

How about [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (assuming you are using Java 7 or later)? If you create object in try section then it will be closed automatically without catching exceptions. The only disadvantage of this approach is that you can still create object outside try section and then it won't be closed.

Comment: This. It's amazing how rarely I see code on SO using this. Anyway, the other disadvantage is that it can't be used for objects with a longer life than the method is created in.

Comment: I've updated the question to show why this isn't a valid solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. What if you would add `start()` method as private, make constructor private and expose to client static factory method where you could use `try-with-resources` + calling `start()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, a class should be responsible for its own state instead of `MyClass` doing job to close resources for other classes. This will also ensure less code changes to `MyClass` with additional new class in future.

IMO, you may try this out:

```
class EarthConnection implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close(){
        /* TO DO */
    }
}

class SolarConnection implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close(){
        /* TO DO */
    }
}

class MyClass {
    private EarthConnection earth;
    private SolarConnection solar;
    public MyClass(EarthConnection earth, SolarConnection solar) {
        this.earth = earth;
        this.solar = solar;
    }
    /* TO DO */
}

try(EarthConnection earth = new EarthConnection()){
    try(SolarConnection solar = new SolarConnection()){ /* exception thrown by this connection*/
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(earth,solar);
        /* TO DO */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do this: instead of constructor, a static method to wrap the ugly code leaving your constructor simple;

In your case, you don't have to catch all exception, only those that come after the first initialization : `solar` is created after `earth` (that's probably not the case in the universe :)), so only if it fails, you'll need to clean `earth` the hard way.

You must not use *try-with-resources* here, because you would close your resource which is not what you want.

```
class MyClass implements AutoCloseable {
  private EarthConnection earth;
  private SolarConnection solar;
     private MyClass(EarthConnection earth, SolarConnection solar) {
        earth = new EarthConnection();
        solar = new SolarConnection(); // exception thrown by this connection
     }

     public static MyClass newMyClass() {
       EarthConnection earth = new EarthConnection();
       try {
         SolarConnection solar = new SolarConnection(); 
         return new MyClass(earth, solar);
       } catch (SolarException e) {
         earth.close(); // may throw, you can ignore it.
         throw e;
       }       
     }
...
}
```

And if you have more than `earth` and `solar`, for example `mars` and `venus`, you would probably need to use a class wrapping `List` of `AutoCloseable`, however your need to close object in reverse order of registering (pretty much like how C++ destructor are called in reverse order of construction).

```
class MyClass implements AutoCloseable {
  private final EarthConnection earth;
  private final VenusConnection venus;
  private final MarsConnection mars;
  private final SolarConnection solar;
  private final AutoCloseable cl;

  private MyClass(
    final EarthConnection earth,
    final VenusConnection venus,
    final MarsConnection mars,
    final SolarConnection solar,
    final AutoCloseable ac
  ) {
    this.earth = earth;
    this.venus = venus;
    this.mars = mars;
    this.solar = solar;
    this.cl = cl;
  }

public static MyClass newMyClass() {
  AutoCloseables cl = new AutoCloseables<>();
  try {
    EarthConnection earth = cl.register(new EarthConnection());
    VenusConnection venus = cl.register(new VenusConnection ());
    MarsConnection  mars = cl.register(new MarsConnection());
    SolarConnection solar = cl.register(new SolarConnection());

    return new MyClass(earth, venus, mars, solar, cl);
  } catch (EarthException | VenusException | MarsException | SolarException e) {
    cl.close();
    throw e; // or new MyClassException(e);
  }
}

@Override
public void close() {
  cl.close();
}
```

With:

```
class AutoCloseables {
  private final List<AutoCloseable> list;
  public <E extends AutoCloseable> E register(E ac) {list.add(ac); return ac;}
  @Override
  public void close() {
    Collections.reverse(list); // destroy in reverse order
    for (AutoCloseable ac : list) {
      try {ac.close();}
      catch (Exception e) {
        // IGNORED or you may use supressedException https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catching `Exception` and rethrowing  should do it. This allows the callers to see the original exception, but allows the cleanup required in the class to close resources.

```
public MyClass() {
    try {
        earth = new EarthConnection();
        solar = new SolarConnection();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        close();
        throw e;
    }
}
```